# How to mock jquery ajax calls, written in jquery.ready function using jasmine test

Tags: jquery, testing, jasmine, gui-testing, jasmine-jquery

I have a scenario where I am calling the jquery ajax inside jquery.ready function. So as soon as this js gets loaded in page, ajax call gets submited. I am writing jasmine test cases for this js. 
Problem is, when I include this js in my specrunner.html for writing jasmine test, jquery.ajax gets called, as it is inside jquery.ready. I want mock this ajax call. I already tried using jasmine ajax, but no help.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to mock the AJAX call, or the response? If it's the latter, In the past I used to mock it with [Sinon's fake server](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server). Now (Jasmine 2.X) has it's own [fake XHR facility](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html). In general you will have in the beforeEach something such as:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  jasmine.Ajax.install();
});
```

Then after you send your request, you'd run:

```
request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
```

and

```
request.respondWith = {
      status: 200,
      responseText: '{"response":{"groups":["A","B","C"]]}}'
}
```